# Fix Flash with Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash, ubuntu-9.04

Tried to use Mozilla's extension installer for running flash plugin installation, and now all flash scripts are showing a big gray play button and won't run.

Should I just uninstall the plugin and install flash by itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can install it with '`apt-get`',
Check these [steps for Ubuntu 9.10](http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/10/how-to-install-firefox-flash-player-in.html) -- should work on 9.04 too.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much success with installing flash plugins or downloading and installing flash from the Adobe site.

Eventually, though, I discovered a web site which described what do immediately after installing Ubuntu. At the time I was using 8.04 LTS

The procedure involved defining a better set of repositories, so that the apt-get update approach worked, and I can watch flash movies.

[this link](http://theindexer.wordpress.com/2009/04/24/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-904-aka-jaunty-jackalope/) is one I just found for 9.04 (not the one I used back in 2007, or something)

The key seemed to be the first step:
**1. Expand the Software Repository List.**